# How to make a new element from an existing one?

Tags: nuclear-physics, elements

So my question is, how can I create a new synthetic element from some existing element. I want to create eka-francium. Now, what would be the best way for me to may it? Should I use a particle accelerator? Perhaps, I can use a proton beam? What element would be good to use for this, like should I shoot francium ions on to iron perhaps? Also, to increase the stability, should I perhaps add in Neutrons or will that be a whole different thing?

Comment: Are we talking about elements from the periodic table? Elements like oxygen, carbon, iron? To make such new ones you'd have to add protons to the nucleus - not exactly a DIY project in the kitchen.

Comment: This is basically atomic fusion / fission - the process that takes place in stars, which gives us almost every heavy element :)

Comment: @Steeven Of course, I never expected it to be a DIY kitchen project. I want to create an element that isn't in the periodic table using an element existing in the periodic table, let's take iron for an example.

Comment: (-1) This is utter nonsense.

Comment: @Aster17 Alright, but I honestly don't understand what is meant by "*I want to create an element*". What are the circumstances here? How would this be done? Are we talking about how it could happen theoretically? Or practically such as with a particle accelerator or some fission machinery? Or naturally such as within stars? Creating a new element is not something that is just done, thus my comment.

Comment: @Max stars fuse the elements up to iron. After that it takes the energy of exploding stars to make any elements heavier than iron.

Comment: @BillAlsept Thank you, I should have been more precise.

Comment: Frankly this sounds like a troll post to me.

Comment: @Steeven I am asking how this could be done practically.

Comment: @StephenG This is not a troll post, I am genuinely asking this question.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that when you say “new synthetic element” you mean an element that has not yet been discovered.

The lightest element that is not yet officially discovered is element 119, provisionally named [ununennium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununennium) or eka-francium. To create it you would need a particle accelerator that can bombard a target of one element with high energy nuclei from another element. In the case of ununennium, attempts have been made to create it by bombarding an einsteinium target with calcium ions, a berkelium target with titanium ions, and a curium target with vanadium ions. All three of these target elements are themselves [transuranium elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transuranium_element) and do not occur in nature. So your first challenge is creating your target.

A small proportion of the bombarding nuclei will strike target nuclei, and an even smaller proportion of these collisions may produce atoms of the type you are looking for. In the case of ununennium it is expected to need at least a year’s worth of runs with a powerful linear accelerator to produce one atom. So your next challenge is finding a source of funding to allow you to buy a large amount of time on one of the world’s half dozen or so most powerful particle accelerators.

Having created an atom of ununennium, your final challenge is to detect it. This will be extraordinarily difficult since ununennium is expected to be very unstable, with a half life of a few tens of microseconds (depending on which isotope of ununennium you have actually created).

The number of protons in a nucleus defines the element concerned. All elements whose nuclei have less than 119 protons have already been discovered or created, and officially named - see [this list of officially recognised elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements). Creating an element with more than 119 protons in its nucleus will be even more difficult than creating ununennium - unless the hypothetical [island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability) actually exists.

A very readable account of the difficulties involved in creating synthetic elements and then proving you have created them can be found in *Superheavy: Making and Breaking the Periodic Table* by Kit Chapman.

Comment: Hi, so I am not trying to make ununennium. I am just trying to make an unnamed element, which I am calling jevillium for now. I just want something that can last atleast 1 year or something. Also, is it possible to maybe use a proton beam instead for this, like take a bar of let's say iron, and then hit it with proton beams. Will that not work?

Comment: @Max Yes, I agree with you. Something that could even probably last a week would be really cool.

Comment: I deleted the comment, because I found that such an element was impossible. Undiscovered elements have an atomic number too high to be stable for even a second, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability

Comment: @Max I am not saying I want to create ununennium. I don't care how many protons are in there. I just want to create a new, unnamed element out of an existing one, like iron or zinc. It doesn't even have to be radioactive, just an element, that is also probably shiny.

Comment: @Aster17 Well, all the elements under an atomic number of 119 are already discovered. You can of course create an alloy from various elements, but that is beside the point.

Comment: @Max So, it isn't possible to make a new element that lasts a considerable amount of time?

Comment: @Aster17 All of the elements whose nuclei have less than 119 protons have already been created and named - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements for a list. Any nuclei with more than 119 protons will be even more difficult to create than ununennium. Even if you want to create a new *isotope* of a known element, this will be extremely difficult and hazardous, since any new isotope will be very unstable and highly  radioactive.

Comment: @Max Can't I create an element with the same number of protons, or will that just become an existing element?

Comment: @Aster17 The thing is that the proton number - called the **atomic number** - is what *defines* elements. Atoms may contain a different number of electrons, of protons and of neutrons. But all those with the same number of protons are given the same name; they are all the same element. They may appear as ions (different number of electrons), as isotopes (different number of neutrons), in excited states (different electron configurations) etc. Some of these combinations are stable and others are not. Regardless, they are all the same element since they have the same number of protons. ...

Comment: @Aster17 ...  Creating a new element *is equivalent to* creating an atom with a new number of protons in the nucleus. Since humankind has already found or created atoms of all proton numbers from 1 up to ~118, you will have to add *even more* protons that 118 in order to get a new element that noone has seen before - and as Max unfortunately mentions, this might be impossible if you want something reasonably stable.

Comment: @Aster17 While the main question has an interesting answer, your question asked in the discussion "Can't I create an element with the same number of protons, or will that just become an existing element?" clearly shows that you have not looked at the very fundamentals of atomic physics at all. An element is *solely* determined by how many protons it has in its core, and *nothing* else. Please consider a quick websearch or reading a wikipedia article before asking a question and starting a lengthy discussion here, because these basics can be found easily.

Comment: @Steeven I get it now, so it isn't  exactly possible to get a new element that is reasonably stable. So, is it possible to make a new element by taking lets say Iron and hitting it with a Proton Beam?